# Uploaded video to firebase should have smae name as original

Tags: android, firebase

I am uploading video to firebase. When a video is uploaded to firebase, it gives a random name to it, but I want an original name. What I mean is when a video called WestWorld is uploaded from my mobile to firebase, the uploaded video in firebase should be called WestWorld.

Comment: What specifically are you using?  Cloud Storage for Firebase?  With that, you're force to give files a name of your choosing.

Comment: I am using firebase storage.  I just mentioned the folder name in which video should be pushed.  Then when i upload a video, firebase automatically gives it a name like video followed by some random number.